# JavaScript function to validate an email address using regular expressions, ensuring it follows the standard format

Tags: javascript, coding-style

implementing a JavaScript function to validate email addresses using regular expressions. The function needs to check whether the provided email address follows the standard format.

typically try using regular expressions in JavaScript to create a pattern that matches the standard format of an email address. You would then test this pattern against the given email address and expect either a match (indicating a valid email address) or no match (indicating an invalid email address).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code that you have worked on to solve the problem be included in your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this it would work.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const emailPattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    return emailPattern.test(email);
}
```